# Need some assistance needed with detecting multiple collisions

Tags: python

I created a simple program consisting of bouncy balls that bounce off the walls and are supposed to turn green upon collision with another ball. However when I add more than 2 balls to the screen, the collision detections falls apart: some balls that collide with one another don't turn green or of the balls that do collide, only one of them turns green. id appreciate it if anybody can look through my code and tell me what the issue is

I detect collisions between balls in the update method of the Ball class.

Here is the Ball class

```
 class Ball:

  def __init__(self,x,y,radius,speed,color=RED):
            self.x=x
            self.y=y
            self.color=color
            self.speed=speed
            self.radius=radius

  def update(self):

       for i in range(0,len(ball)):
          for j in range(0,len(ball)):

            if i==j:
                continue

            elif is_collision(ball[i],ball[j]):
                ball[i].color=GREEN
                ball[j].color=GREEN

            else:
                ball[i].color=RED
                ball[j].color=RED

    def draw(self):  

        pygame.draw.circle(screen,self.color(self.x,self.y),radius)
```

This is the rest of the code outside of the class

```
def is_collision(ball1, ball2):

    distance = math.hypot(ball2.x - ball1.x, ball2.y - ball1.y)

    if distance<=ball1.radius+ball2.radius:
        return True
    else:
        return False

for i in range(number_balls):                 # adds balls to list

    rX=random.randint(radius,WIDTH-radius)
    rY=random.randint(radius,HEIGHT-radius)

    dx=random.randint(1,10)
    dy=random.randint(1,10)

    rC1=random.randint(0,255)
    rC2=random.randint(0,255)
    rC3=random.randint(0,255)

    rColor=(rC1,rC2,rC3)


    ball.append(Ball(rX,rY,25,[dx,dy]))


while True:                         # main loop

for events in pygame.event.get():
    if events.type==pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()

    for x in ball:

        x.x+=x.speed[0]
        x.y+=x.speed[1]

        if x.x-x.radius<0 or x.x+x.radius>WIDTH:
           x.speed[0]=-x.speed[0]

        if x.y-x.radius<0 or x.y+x.radius>HEIGHT:
           x.speed[1]=-x.speed[1]

        x.draw()
        x.update()

   pygame.display.update()
   screen.fill(BLACK)
```

Assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could use some form of a BVH or BSP tree like a dynamic AABB tree to reduce inspections

Comment: @pstatix No need to be dynamic. Even just a non-adaptive subdivision grid would be effective in reducing the coefficient of the quadratic.

Comment: @DanD. Only reason I suggested dynamic was because it seems like this is a game with moving pieces, so the tree would need cycle updates from redraws.